# Is there any way to enforce the use of a JMS message selector?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, message-queue, java-ee-7

I am currently testing out JMS queue (first time using JMS) and message driven beans. 
I have created a queue to provide other applications with state updates for one of our projects.

Logic is written in native JMS, deployed on a JBOSS7 using the ActiveMQ implementation.

It depends on a selector to deliver the messages to the right client, and while I can just place good faith in my colleagues, preferably I would like to enforce the use of the selector so the clients don't consume messages not meant for them.

So basically I would prefer that no messages are delivered to a client which has not specified a selector.

When I deploy a consumer without any selector it just consumes all messages available on the queue.

Otherwise everything works as expected.

I have looked and haven't been able to find anything I am looking for, maybe it's possible by configuring ActiveMQ itself but I am not really at home in that ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is resolved by using a system I wasn't that aware about and I thought I'd share it here if someone need it:

The JMS clients are on different physical machines so originally the plan was to do manual JNDI remote lookup to access the queue but this caused some problems. Mainly having to write retry logic when the Queue is unavailable.

I threw that plan out the window to opt for a Bridge instead, following the guide found here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/howto/jboss-jms6/configuring-jms-bridge-with-wildfly-10

This has multiple advantages (both the producer system or the client can go down without causing too many problems) but most notably this solves my problem: I can define a selector on the bridge per Client. So the responsibility of choosing who receives which messages is back in my court.

I will have a crack at implementing this.